# Display picture in my HTML file with Django Media

Tags: html, django, url

I would like to import picture from my Django media folder to my HTML file but it doesn't seems to work up to now.

My settings.py file looks like :

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join('/Users/terii/Desktop/Django/Project A', 'Photos_Identifications/')
```

In my HTML file, I have :

```
{% if object.Image %}

            Methode 1 : <img src="http://localhost:8000/media/pictures/test.jpg"/> #It works
            <br></br>
            Methode 2 : <img src="/Users/terii/Desktop/Django/Project A/Photos_Identifications/pictures/test.jpg"/> #It works
            <br></br>
            Methode 3 : <img src="{{ MEDIA_URL}}{{object.Image}}"/> #It doesn't work
        {% endif %}
```

I don't why my `Method 3` doesn't work and I would like to know if you had any idea ? I don't want to write the entire path, because it should be dynamic.

Thank you :)

Comment: if you inspect your html page on your browser what do you get as url on the img src using `{{MEDIA_URL}}{{object.Image}}` ?

Comment: If I print `settings.MEDIA_URL` : `/media/` and if I print `settings.MEDIA_ROOT` : `/Users/terii/Desktop/Django/Project A/Photos_Identifications/`. And if I print `object.Image` : `pictures/test.jpg`. So `src="{{MEDIA_ROOT}}{{object.Image}}` should work :/

Comment: There is one more information : I'm using `pisa` from `xhtml2pdf`

Answer (score 1):

You dont have to use media url 
Just try this

```
<img src="{{object.Image.url}}"/>
```

Comment: Assuming the webserver knows the `/media/` location, but yeah. It'll work with `python manage.py runserver` at least.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. The problem comes from `Pisa library`.

I added in my views.py file :

```
def link_callback(uri, rel):
    if uri.find('chart.apis.google.com') != -1:
        return uri
    return os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, uri.replace(settings.MEDIA_URL, ""))
```

Then,

```
pdf = pisa.pisaDocument(StringIO.StringIO(html.encode("utf-8")), file, link_callback=link_callback)
```

And it works with :

```
<img src="{{MEDIA_ROOT}}{{object.Image.url}}" width="200" height="150"/>
```

in my HTML file !